# Converting an old pc to a server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, windows-server-2012

I have this crazy idea of setting up my own server by converting an old pc.
I read this article from [instuctables.com](http://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-an-old-Computer-into-a-web-server/).

But now I want to dig deeper to know that if I set up my PC according to the instructions from the above link how can I enforce a good amount of ***security***. I would also like to know which OS should I run so that I and my friend can use it for deploying apps built on **ASP, JSP, PHP, PYTHON, MySQL**.

Also is it possible to set up features like mailing, SSH on it?

Comment: Does it have dual power supplies, out of band management capabilities, error-correctly memory, is your server OS supported on the entirety of your hardware? We don't mess around here, we're a site for professional sysadmins who build and manage supportable systems using professional hardware and software - there are other sites for people just hacking together their left overs.

Comment: I know this question might be stupid and vague but I didnt get any good search results and am a novice in this field without much resources to build professional stuff.

Comment: Please read, instead of ignoring as you have, our help pages and observe the workings of the site before posting again. We can't support your plan to utilise a 17 year old CPU in a production environment.

Comment: Sounds like a nice weekend project for my 8 yo son. Production? Never.

Comment: Yep I get that. That's why I said it to be a crazy idea. And since it doesn't seem fit for the site, kindly ask the moderator to shift the question to a proper site as I should not be deleting a question with an answer. AND I believe its always better to learn driving on an old car before getting a new one especially when you dont know how to drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It it possible, but still depends on the computer specification.

I would recommend Linux based : CentOS or Ubuntu.

Base on my experience, i have a pentium 4 , 2gb ram and 80gb hdd that running CentOS that run ftp,web services , c++ compilers without any hiccups.

Here the link:

ASP : https://gist.github.com/F2006/ed0dbc7f0f7de6e3297ef21e1bfb8682

JSP :  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get

PHP & MySql : http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-install-lamp-on-ubuntu

Phyton : https://askubuntu.com/questions/449555/how-to-install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu

Regards

Comment: How do I set it up other than installing the OS? The computer specs am talking about are: pentium4, 2gb ram and160GB HDD. I need to run all the above mentioned things.

Comment: What do u mean to set it up?

Comment: I mean after installing ubuntu server/ CentOS, how do I get it ready to run ASP, JSP, PHP, PYTHON, MySQL?

Comment: By getting it done one by one :

Comment: Can all the above be run on CentOS/ Ubuntu? Because I read somewhere that we cant run JSP on linux environment

Comment: I update my answer above, JSP can be run by using Java servlet container or Java EE application server running on the server . Commonly used servlet container is Apache Tomcat.

Comment: Loads of thanks. I will definitely look through. You were a lot of help. :)